# elasticsearch routing on single field

Tags: elasticsearch

On searching with routing it giving me data of different routing keys also.
Please help me out.

I have set routing in v2.0 and i queried query with routing key,below is example:

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search?routing=5
 {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
 } 
}
```

I have search data with routing key=5 but output i get was:

```
    hits": [
     {
        "_index": "goqii",
        "_type": "nazar",
        "_id": "2047",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "10",
        "_source": {
           "userId": "111239",
           "activityId": "765982",
           "activityUserId": "111239",
           "activityType": "water",
           "commentText": "kinu juice",
           "status": "delievered",
           "createdTime": "2016-01-13 13:28:54"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "goqii",
        "_type": "nazar",
        "_id": "2046",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "5",
        "_source": {
           "userId": "110554",
           "activityId": "251449",
           "activityUserId": "110554",
           "activityType": "activity",
           "commentText": "did home cycling yesterday for 20mins",
           "status": "delievered",
           "createdTime": "2016-01-13 12:04:31"
        }
     }
```

It is giving me routing key:5 & routing key:10 boths data.please help me out if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Use POST when sending the query in the payload

Comment: It giving me same output.

Comment: Which client are you using to send your query?

Comment: i am using sense plugin of chrome.Apart from that i am using Php-curl to send Request.And my routing is calculated by this theory.... routing=(userId %10) +1

Answer (score 0):

Routing doesnt gaurantee that all the items on a shard will have the same routing key, it will `make sure that all the docs that share a routing key are all on the same shard`.

Routing is the process of determining which shard that document will reside in.

How many shards do you have in your index? It defaults to 5.

The scenario seems that you have the default number of shards in your index.

> Routing scheme hashes the ID of a document and uses that to find a
>   shard. Routing ensures that documents of a particular routing value all go to the same shard…but that doesn’t mean that other documents aren’t routed to the shard too.

In your case both userIds "110554" and "111239" may be getting assigned to the same shard, hence the behavior.

Comment: KK0608: can you tell if you have 5 primary + 5 replica or 10 primary + 10 replica. In the former case, then @rahulroc's answer makes sense.

Comment: @KK0608, can you please provide your index settings so that I can check the exact number of shards